# Find values from JSON with unknown structure SWIFT

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

I read some questions about parsing JSON with unknown strucutre. But these questions are not in Swift and don't solve my issue.

I have a big JSON file that I obtain with a Alamofire HTTP request. Here is it: https://pastebin.com/Y7cWSWAt

In fact, the JSON could change with requests I do. It will not always be the same structure depending of the user (for example). However, there will be the same keys and values.

So I know the keys in the JSON to find the values, their will be always the same. But I don't know how to access them. Moreover, my JSON has an `Any` type (I can't give him a specific type because I don't know it).

**My question:** Is there a solution to find values with this? Can I loop throw all the JSON values to find specific keys and values? Is it better to work with JSON file or Dictionaries? I have no code yet because I have no idea. Thanks mates!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use just NSDictionary this not problem but when return array json your app will be crash because variable type not be equals.

```
let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)
if json != nil {
    let obj = json as? NSDictionary
}
//this part write all key and value 
for (key, value) in obj {
        print("Property: \"\(key as String)\", Value: \"\(value as String)\"")
    }
```

input: `{"test1":"value1","test2":"value2"}`

output:

```
Property: "test1", Value: "value1"
Property: "test2", Value: "value2"
```

Comment: This doesn't work because, if you look the JSON structure, it's not as `[String : String]`. It is more complicated...

Comment: [String:String] mean is same "key":"value" / NSDictionary if your json value is not array this probably work. your json have more object and array you can't see keys without don't know keys just try second part in code do debug you will see all values

Comment: yes but it your json starting with object  { } not array [] you can see all value in inside

Comment: Output: `Property: "total", Value: "0"
Property: "children", Value: "(
        {
        Title = "2016-2017 ( 8/1/2016 - 10/31/2017 )";
        children =         (`

Comment: That's not what I want

Comment: I want all the values for key "MarkValue". You see?

Comment: children's value is comlicated you can't understand this different value from anothers just see like this. if json allways return same keys create struct

Comment: It seems like this is impossible

Comment: did you get a solution to this?

Comment: One problem I see is that if you want the key "children" in your file to be considered a string it should have double-quotes around it (just as I have typed here).  There's no rule that says keys have to be strings, but it's probable that you are using [String: Any] or [String: String] or [String: Double] (etc.)  as an implicit default for building your dictionary somewhere in your code.